# Find a function whose first partial with respect to $x$ does not exist.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I'm having a difficult time understanding what it means for a first partial derivative of a function to exist. I was wondering if someone could come up with an example of a function defined in the $xy$-plane whose first partial with respect to $x$ does not exist, and show this using the definition of derivative?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Find a function $g: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ whose derivative doesn't exist somewhere, and then define $f(x,y)=g(x).$

Answer (score 1):

How about $f(x,y)=\ln x$?  The partial derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y)=\frac1x$  at $(0,y)$ doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I think that I was most confused about figuring out if a partial derivative exits when the denominator is nonzero. Since I assume one would then have to check to see that the left and right hand limits of $f_x$ agree, right?

Comment: Yes.  I guess you could also consider something like $f(x,y)=\mid x\mid$, with a "sharp point".